# The largest negative root of the trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

$$
f(x) = 2\cos^2 x + 9\sin x - 6 
$$

1. Find (in degrees) the largest negative root of the equation $f(x) = 0$.
2. Find (in degrees) the smallest positive integer value of $x$ for which  inequality $f(x) > 0$.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, so that we know where to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**
\begin{align*} 
f(x) &= 2\bigl(1-\sin^2(x)\bigr)+9\sin(x)-6 \\
&= -2\sin^2(x)+8\sin(x)+\sin(x)-4 \\
&= -2\sin(x)\bigl(\sin(x)-4\bigr)+\bigl(\sin(x)-4\bigr) \\
&= \bigl(\sin(x)-4\bigr)\bigl(1-2\sin(x)\bigr) 
\end{align*}

So
$$f(x)=0\iff \sin(x)=\frac 12$$
and
$$f(x)>0\iff \sin(x)>\frac 12$$

Comment: Thanks for editing. could i know who did it ? to thank him again.

Comment: Sammy Black edited it.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Thanks again and again.

Comment: My pleasure. You can see who edited it by clicking on the blue writing which currently says 'edited 9 mins ago' below your post; it shows all previous edits and editors.